# Why am I unable to run ImagePolicyWebhook service as a regular ClusterIP service on the same cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

So I followed the instructions on https://github.com/flavio/kube-image-bouncer, but instead of installing it on the host or running in a docker I have arranged it as a ClusterIP service running on the same cluster. Temporarily, of course. Consider this an exercise.

Anyway, the service is working fine:

```
mark@cks-master:~ $ k exec test -- curl -s https://kube-image-bouncer.kube-image-bouncer.svc/image_policy --cacert /webhook.pem && echo
{"message":"Method Not Allowed"}
mark@cks-master:~ $
```

So, I have created all the necessary configuration, made the changes to the kube-apiserver static pod and:

```
mark@cks-master:~ $ k run test2 --image nginx
Error from server (Forbidden): pods "test2" is forbidden: Post "https://kube-image-bouncer.kube-image-bouncer.svc/image_policy?timeout=30s": dial tcp: lookup kube-image-bouncer.kube-image-bouncer.svc on 168.63.129.16:53: no such host
mark@cks-master:~ $
```

This looks like `kube-image-bouncer.kube-image-bouncer.svc` fails to resolve. But I know it resolves just fine when running in a pod - see the previous `curl` example.

I thought that the admission controllers are run by the kube-controller-manager, i.e. on a pod and thus should have no problem resolving `kube-image-bouncer.kube-image-bouncer.svc`.

Obviously, I misunderstand something. Can someone explain what is going on?